# getting different expires_at values for user access token using facebook graph APII

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have the user login and grant my app permissions

In the redirect after the login, I exchange the code for a long lived token and with that long lived token i get an expires_in value

i then set that expires_in in my database.

I then take this long lived token and call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=<lltoken>&access_token=<my app token>
```

it returns

```
"data_access_expires_at": 1614276511, 
"expires_at": 0,
```

I am confused why i am getting different expires_at results.  Is this not the correct way to determine when a long lived user access token is going to expire?

Thanks

Comment: Different than - what? It looks like you might have an extended page access token here, those do not have any default expiry, so `"expires_at": 0`

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your response. So i am probably confused or using wrong terminology

the first time i grant access to the app as a user , my redirect URL is called. in the payload of that POST to my redirect URL is a code

I then take that code and call 
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/oauth/access_token?client_id="+facebookAppId+"&redirect_uri="+facebookLoginRedirectURL+"&client_secret="+facebookAppSecret+"&code="+code

this returns a token and expires_at

This is the token i save to my DB. Is this not a user_token?

this is the token i call the call debug

Comment: Yes, that would be a user token. But if you are asking for permission that will enable you to get a page access token, and then extend the user token, the user token will not have a default expiry (because an extended page token has none, and the page token is tied to the specific user account it was granted from.) It might expire due to other factors though, f.e. if the user changes their account password.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for all this info. So how do i get the expiration of the user token? thanks

Comment: If it says `"expires_at": 0`, then it doesn’t have one.